# Removing Ubuntu 12.10 and back to Windows 7

Tags: 12.10, windows, uninstall

I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop that came standard with Windows 7.  I figured I'd give Ubuntu a try but now I'm finding that I prefer Windows.  I was unaware that I could have Ubuntu as well as Windows before I downloaded it and I don't know how to revert back without a disc.  Would a system restore work?  I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge about this kind of thing but I would really like to revert back.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has a recovery partition (and you didn't delete it when installing Ubuntu) then you can boot to that. Check the PC manufacturer's website for instructions specific to your computer.

If not, however, then reinstalling from a Windows Disc is your only recourse.

For future reference; if you ever want to try any Ubuntu distribution you can burn it to a CD and boot to it, then try it out without installing. This makes it easier to audition without the danger of losing your current OS.